# How to recycle List<Color> index?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ListViewBuilder which will propagate a reusable container based on a firestore database and it will pull a separate list of colours such as this one to colour the reusable container:

```
List<Color> colours = [
    Color(0xFFFB5A50),
    Color(0xFF26E29E),
    Color(0xFFffc452),
    Color(0xFF7773FB),
  ];
```

My Question is, because the list from the database may be over 100 in quantity. How would you
continuous reuse the colours List without going out of listrange?

Comment: Like if my database length is 100 and when my listview.separated build a widget at  index 54 for e.g, the range would be more than my List<Color> colours range as the max range is 3. How do I recycle the colour list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use operator %, for exsample:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.separated(
      itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        return Container(
          height: 40,
          color: colours[index % colours.length],
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (_, index) => SizedBox(height: 8),
    ),
  );
}
```

More info about this operator : [dart operator % method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/double/operator_modulo.html)

Comment: Thanks Shenjing! That did the magic. Never thought of using the % operator. Will read up about it. Thanks!